# How to list the data save in SQLite using Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, desktop-application, syncfusion

Currently, I am developing a desktop application in which I have saved the data in the database, now problem is that I am facing difficulties in listing the saved data on to screen. Below are the complete code files.

database_helper.dart

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  final databaseName = "auth.db";
  String newphase = '''
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newphase(
  srNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  phaseName TEXT,
  landinAcers INTEGER,
  landinmarlas INTEGER,
  description TEXT
  )
  ''';
Future<Database> initDB() async {
    print("initDB executed");
    try {
      String databaseName = 'auth.db';
      final databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
      final path = join(databasePath, databaseName);
      return openDatabase(path, version: 2, onCreate: (db, version) async {
        await db.execute(newphase);
      });
    }catch (e) {
      print("Error initializing database: $e");
      rethrow;
    }
  }

 Future<int> addNewPhase(NewPhase newphase) async {
    final Database db = await initDB();
    return db.insert('newphase', newphase.toMap());
  }


  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getPhases() async {
    final Database db = await initDB();
    List<Map<String, Object?>> data = await db.query('newphase',);
    print("Data is " + data.toString());
    Map newPhase = data[0];
    print("Sr No is ${newphase[0].toString()}");
    print("Name is ${newphase[1].toString()}");
    return data;
  }
}
```

newphase_json.dart

```
    import 'dart:convert';

NewPhase newPhaseFromMap(String str) => NewPhase.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String newPhaseToMap(NewPhase data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class NewPhase {
  final int? srNo;
  final String phaseName;
  final String landInAcers;
  final String landInMarlas;
  final String description;

  NewPhase({
    this.srNo,
    required this.phaseName,
    required this.landInAcers,
    required this.landInMarlas,
    required this.description,
  });

  factory NewPhase.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NewPhase(
    srNo: json["srNo"],
    phaseName: json["phaseName"],
    landInAcers: json["landInAcers"],
    landInMarlas: json["landInMarlas"],
    description: json["description"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "srNo": srNo,
    "phaseName": phaseName,
    "landInAcers": landInAcers,
    "landInMarlas": landInMarlas,
    "description": description,
  };
}
```

add_new_phase_form.dart

```
import '../../SQLite/newphase_json.dart';
import '../../utils/app_layout.dart';
import '../../utils/dependencies.dart';
import '../../widgets/elevated_button.dart';
import '../../SQLite/database_helper.dart';

class AddNewPhaseForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddNewPhaseForm({super.key});

  @override
  _AddNewPhaseFormState createState() => _AddNewPhaseFormState();
}

class _AddNewPhaseFormState extends State<AddNewPhaseForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final phaseName = TextEditingController();
  final landInAcers = TextEditingController();
  final landInMarlas = TextEditingController();
  final description = TextEditingController();
  final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper();
  var homeController = Get.put(HomeController());

  addnewphase() async {
    var res = await db.addNewPhase(NewPhase(
      phaseName: phaseName.text,
      landInAcers: landInAcers.text, landInMarlas: landInMarlas.text,
        description: description.text,

    ));
    if (res > 0) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      homeController.changeIndex(1);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Record added successfully!'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 5), // Adjust duration as needed
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = AppLayout.getSize(context);
    return Container(
        width: size.width * 1,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), color: Colors.white),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Add New Phase',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontFamily: 'Quicksand-SemiBold',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: phaseName,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Phase Name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter phase name';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      controller: landInAcers,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Land In Acers', border: OutlineInputBorder(),),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter land in acers';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: landInMarlas,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Land in Marlas', border: OutlineInputBorder(),),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter Land in Marlas';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: description,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description', border: OutlineInputBorder(),),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter Description';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    CustomElevatedButton(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 50,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      text: 'Add New',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Quicksand-SemiBold',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){
                        addnewphase();
                        print('record added...');
                      }
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

phase_list.dart

```
import '../../tabels/add_new_phase_list.dart';
import '../../utils/app_layout.dart';
import '../../utils/dependencies.dart';

class PhaseListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhaseListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = AppLayout.getSize(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF2F7FB),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 45,
                  width: 45,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    color: Colors.blue
                  ),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.landscape, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
                const Text(
                  'Phase List',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontFamily: 'Quicksand-SemiBold',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            NewAddedPahseList(),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

add_new_phase_list.dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:new_city/SQLite/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';
import '../utils/app_layout.dart';
import '../utils/dependencies.dart';


class NewAddedPahseList extends StatefulWidget {
  NewAddedPahseList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewAddedPahseListState createState() => _NewAddedPahseListState();
}

class _NewAddedPahseListState extends State<NewAddedPahseList> {
  late List<Map> newPhases;
  late PhasesDataSource phasesDataSource;
  var homeController = Get.put(HomeController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    newPhases = getPhaseData() as List<Map>;
    phasesDataSource = PhasesDataSource(phaseData: newPhases);
  }

  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  String _searchText = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = AppLayout.getSize(context);
    return Container(
      width: size.width * 1,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), color: Colors.white),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                homeController.changeIndex(30);
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 45,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  color: Colors.blue
                ),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Add New',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular',
                        color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
             Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _searchController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Search',
                      hintText: 'Enter your search query',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _searchText = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            SfDataGrid(
              source: phasesDataSource,
              columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
              allowSorting: true,
              allowMultiColumnSorting: true,
              sortingGestureType: SortingGestureType.tap,
              rowsPerPage: 0,
              columns: <GridColumn>[
                GridColumn(
                  columnName: 'serNo',
                  label: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: const Text('Sr. No' , style:
                    TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Quicksand-SemiBold',
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),),
                  ),
                ),
                GridColumn(
                  columnName: 'name',
                  label: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: const Text('Phase Name', style:
                    TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Quicksand-SemiBold',
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 't_area',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Total Area in Acers',style:
                        TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Quicksand-SemiBold',
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        ))),
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 't_plot',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Total Plot', style:
                        TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Quicksand-SemiBold',
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                          //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ))),
             
                GridColumn(
                  columnName: 'action',
                  label: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: const Text('Action' , style:
                    TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Quicksand-SemiBold',
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SfDataPager(pageCount: 5, delegate: DataPagerDelegate()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<Map>> getPhaseData() async {
    return await DatabaseHelper().getPhases();
  }
}

/// Custom business object class which contains properties to hold the detailed
/// information about the employee which will be rendered in datagrid.
class NewPhases {
  NewPhases(this.serNo, this.name, this.t_area,  this.t_plot,  this.price);
  final int serNo;
  final String name;
  final int t_area;
  final int t_plot;
  final int price;
}

/// An object to set the employee collection data source to the datagrid. This
/// is used to map the employee data to the datagrid widget.
class PhasesDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  /// Creates the employee data source class with required details.
  PhasesDataSource({required List<Map> phaseData}) {
    _phaseData = phaseData
    .map<DataGridRow>((e) => DataGridRow(cells: [
    DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'serNo', value: e.length),
    DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: e.toString()),
    DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 't_area', value: e.length),
    DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 't_plot', value: e.length),
    DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'action', value: e.length),
    ])).toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> _phaseData = [];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => _phaseData;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((e) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
            child:e.columnName == 'action'?Row(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: const Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.blue,),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width:10),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red,),
                ),
              ],
            ):Text(e.value.toString(), style: const TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular',
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: Color(0xff2f2e2e),
            ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList());
  }
}
```

Currently, the data is saving successfully but faces an issue in listing the data

Comment: please,share what issue is getting
and the code to list

Comment: the issue i am facing : The following _TypeError was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#83b7a]:
type 'Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' in type cast

Comment: we are getting closer,
now show the code (widget tha should show the list )

Comment: where should I send the file of list data code

Comment: just need to see the piece of code that is calling the  method "getPhases"

Comment: I have just added the code please check it

Comment: @ Ildeberto Vasconcelos now face new issue can you please cehck:  
The following LateError was thrown building NewAddedPahseList(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _NewAddedPahseListState#44c8a):
LateInitializationError: Field 'phasesDataSource' has not been initialized.

Comment: ok,this happens when you try to use a object before initialize it
i've edit my answer
first init the phasesDataSource
then call the fetchInitData() method
and the the List of newPhases shoul be an empty array instead of late
check my edited answer on the main post

Comment: List<Map> newPhases=[]; by using this it display the empty table on screen no data in it

Comment: then call the setState  or update the screen after fetch the phases and  everytime add a new phase (check the answer again) 

 but any left errors?

Comment: no error was found but not data was displayed on the screen as data displayed in the console

Comment: just need to update the screen by calling setState((){});
did you tried ?

Comment: yes I tried it: fetchInitData() async {
    newPhases =await  getPhaseData();
    setState((){
    });
  }

Comment: ok,think i found the problem
set again :
phasesDataSource = PhasesDataSource(phaseData: newPhases); 

before setState

Comment: Yes, it is working now but only displays srNo: in phase name column just that are auto increment in Database not other displays in tabe as all is display in console: Data is [{srNo: 1, phaseName: Zaman, landinAcers: 5, landinmarlas: 3, description: hsvgv},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **initState** method cannot be async

so,on your `NewAddedPahseList`  widget

create a new method  like this

```
fetchInitData() async {
newPhases =await  getPhaseData();
phasesDataSource = PhasesDataSource(phaseData: newPhases); 
setState((){});
}
```

and call this method on initState

```
@override
 void initState() {
  phasesDataSource = PhasesDataSource(phaseData: newPhases); 
  fetchInitData();
 super.initState();    
}
```

You need to handle the asynchronous nature of the Future to access its value.

and replace

```
 late List<Map> newPhases;
```

by:

```
List<Map> newPhases=[];
```